# Boolean + Subdivision modifier warped surface

Tags: modeling, modifiers, workflow

I was following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WxMwa0njGSM), but I am not getting the mesh to work correctly with subdivision surface.

[image]

I was using the boolean modifier to cut my mesh, and was stressed that subdivision surface was causing my mesh's surface/geometry to be warped after applying that boolean modifier.

The problem was that I was using the exact solver instead of fast(in bool modifier), and choosing the fast solver fixed the geometry warping, presumably because the exact method was causing some imperfections that I made when trying to align two objects.

[image]

Comment: Edit your title to something more specific, attach a screenshot of your issue, append simplified blend via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ Remember this site is knowledge base, so others can find answers from questions of others. Your title is meaningless, external links are not allowed, they are not permanent. Thank you to keep this site helpful.

Comment: No problem. I assumed that this was a popular tutorial so didn't think I needed to explain myself much.

Comment: Thanks for improvements :) Popular or not Andrew can decide to remove it any time and here nobody will understand what are you talking about. To avoid this broken links - all important part should be included here. I did few more edits (you can anytime to revert  changes to previous). Anyway your edit looks like you also answering your issue in last senetence too. If so please move this part into your answer section via edit.

Comment: Your question would be probably a duplication, but I voted to reopen it since you improved your question - with  question like that we can easier to get into your issue and others can learn from this post. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Well, I figured it out myself. I just needed to delete the bottom face.